# How to listen session:success event in nexmo client js?

Tags: vonage

I follow tutorial here: https://developer.nexmo.com/client-sdk/tutorials/app-to-phone/client-sdk/app-to-phone/main-screen/javascript

listen `session:success` event with bellow script not working.

```
const status = $('.input');

app.on('session:success', () => {
 status.val('Ready to call.');
});
```

Is there any other event i can listen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems i don't need to listen nexmo app event.

Just check it with if condition.

```
if (app.session.sessionReady) {
 callStatus.val("Ready for call.");
}
```